How to scroll to a php page id from another page
I tried to reproduce the problem in the code below. I have 2 pages index.php and confirmation.php. Index.php contains sections with ids once the user submits a form he can get back to where he was using the script1 as below. Then after submitting the final form the user is send to  confirmation.php page. Here if I try to do the same thing location.href = 'localhost/folder/confirmation.php/#sectionid1' the page appears as if no css was added (if I remove #sectionid1 everything looks fine. Now once the user complete the confirmation form he is send back to the thankyou section in index.php using same type of script and here also it works properly. So why it is not working within the page confirmation.php (I have no console error, no php error).
script1
?>
<script>
    location.href='#details'
</script>
<?php

Here is the code to use for index.php and for check.php that showcase the problem in each file. Within each file works fine, but when you try to scroll to #second in check.php from index.php with
this script
function getAnchor(){
    location.href = 'check.php/#second'
}

then it won't work (and no more css).
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <section id="first">
        <p>section 1</p>
        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam, nam. Id, voluptates corrupti illum ea vitae deleniti rem debitis unde voluptatem perspiciatis! Similique illum nihil, perspiciatis reiciendis quas laudantium eum.
        Placeat atque odio excepturi fugit modi, distinctio, ex rem quia deserunt, voluptatibus veritatis officiis sint recusandae doloribus deleniti sapiente. Consectetur possimus ad a excepturi animi fuga, deserunt repellat ipsum eum.
        Accusamus nisi magni inventore dolore totam quam! Unde quas ut dicta numquam maiores ipsa illum praesentium beatae totam accusamus voluptate velit vitae necessitatibus, hic fugit consequuntur repudiandae adipisci esse. Voluptates.
        Consequatur similique eveniet pariatur libero odio assumenda totam dolore maiores neque, tempora dolorum exercitationem deserunt possimus a atque saepe repudiandae enim vero optio. Natus corrupti delectus aliquid sunt itaque saepe.
    <section id="second">
        <p>section 2</p>
        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus ea alias at, minus eius, maxime deleniti quam unde explicabo dolores suscipit itaque, eligendi eum perferendis! Reprehenderit illum nihil quis excepturi?
        Tempore aperiam ipsam sapiente culpa totam veritatis modi minima illo amet labore ratione sint aliquid, itaque vel iusto dolorem assumenda voluptatum ullam libero perferendis accusamus doloremque aut obcaecati. Vel, tenetur.
        Eius, aspernatur dicta? Repellat, ducimus? Laboriosam praesentium, deserunt voluptatum enim eaque nobis consequuntur, rem, accusamus reprehenderit error pariatur cumque quod voluptatem ipsum minima! Officiis harum molestias autem ex iusto quidem.
        Iusto ad mollitia quidem sint culpa, omnis quas nihil iste ratione, dolorem eius quia voluptate dolorum, unde corrupti molestias. Impedit porro quis temporibus error eius soluta ipsum minus vero aperiam?
        Corrupti harum officia soluta. Hic quia eaque quae officia eveniet necessitatibus laboriosam magnam blanditiis suscipit? Maiores neque provident consequatur aliquam est labore, sit quibusdam sequi facere. Suscipit delectus deleniti obcaecati!
        Omnis ducimus voluptates, obcaecati non repellendus ea sed aliquam quia eligendi in culpa animi sequi sint maiores at nulla vero officia et a unde! Iure eum enim deserunt quas ipsum?
    </section>
    <section id="third">
        <p>section 3</p>
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam aperiam voluptatum voluptates sunt ipsam nemo! Earum rem aut itaque. In modi veniam inventore dolorem expedita laboriosam vitae, omnis suscipit vel?
        Quos sunt voluptatibus maxime architecto. Expedita tempore vel ratione eos. Quas a delectus quo culpa perferendis beatae? Impedit, voluptas quibusdam nesciunt nemo optio autem deserunt blanditiis fugit ipsa id asperiores.
        Ratione blanditiis tempora maiores magnam velit voluptatum nihil unde quidem voluptates perferendis incidunt facere obcaecati quaerat optio, reprehenderit excepturi nam atque qui eveniet. Vitae, iusto? Ex quasi odit officiis distinctio?
        In quidem cum est mollitia iure impedit, quam saepe amet fugiat porro vel et, laudantium voluptatem beatae minima officiis esse facere itaque perferendis placeat eveniet aut dolores repellendus? Necessitatibus, sint?
</section>
</div>  
 <button onclick="getAnchor()">click</button>
</body>

.wrapper{
  max-height: 25vh;
  overflow-Y: auto;
}

function getAnchor(){
    location.href = '#second'
}

What I am I doing wrong?

try localhost/folder/confirmation.php#sectionid1, instead of localhost/folder/confirmation.php/#sectionid1, and 'check.php#second', instead of 'check.php/#second'

Do you have ever used https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView ?

As far as I remember, you should place anchor tags with name property at the location where to scroll. <a name="details">

"Here is the code to use for index.php and for check.php" does not contain an element with name or id attribute set to "sectionid1". If you want the same location value to work in both pages. the pages would need to be in the same server folder. Are they? Please clarify how to reproduce the problem.

... note you could make demonstration code a lot shorter by setting, say, a background color for section elements and any short text for content - If the CSS goes missing they won't be colored.

@Yarin_007 thanks a lot James that is correct doing that let my confirmation.php scroll to the desired section id. If you can post an answer for others SO users to see, I will indeed as well check correct answer. Again thanks a lot for your help.

@deEr thanks a lot for your suggestion it is very interesting and did not really know about scrollIntoView() method. Think however will work in same page but not when changing page (tried it as well). Thank you very much again deEr

@IT goldman, thanks a lot, yes you can use either an id="second" or place an anchor tag with name  will have same effect. the correct command was as suggested by Yarin_007 when using location.href. Again thanks a lot for your help

@traktor thanks for your help. yes id or a tag will give same result. the problem was in the command syntax and the correct way was as suggested by Yarin_007. Thank you very much for your help.

@Mehdi You are welcome. Found out, that I wanted to show you this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign .  Instead of the link I sent.
